# SSIS Data Flow Task Excel Source

Tags: excel, ssis

I have a data flow task set up in SSIS.

The source is from an Excel source not an SQL DB.

The problem i seem to get is that, the package is importing empty rows.

My data has data in 555200 rows, but however when importing the SSIS package imports over 900,000 rows.  The extra rows are imported even though the other empty.

When i then download this table into excel there are empty rows in between the data.

Is there anyway i can avoid this?

Thanks

Gerard

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682824/ssis-dataflow-from-excel-empty-rows

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do. If you can, is export the data to a flat file, csv or tab, and then read it in. The problem is even though those rows are blank they are not really empty. So when you hop across that ODBC-Excel bridge you are getting those rows as blanks.

You could possibly adjust the way the spreadsheet is generated to eliminate this problem or manually the delete the rows. The problem with these solutions is that they are not scalable or maintainable over the long term. You will also be stuck with that rickety ODBC bridge. The best long term solution is to avoid using the ODBC-Excel bridge entirely. By dumping the data to a flat file you have total control over how to read, validate, and interpret the data. You will not be at the mercy of a translation layer that is to this day riddled with bugs and is at the best of times "quirky"

Answer (score 0):

You can also add in a Conditional Split component in your Data flow task, between the source task and the destination task. In here, check if somecolumn is null or empty - something that is consistent - meaning for every valid row, it has some data, and for every invalid row it's empty or null.

Then discard the output for that condition, sending the rest of the rows to the destination. You should then only get the amount of rows with valid data from Excel.